# Replace env variables in the .npmrc with dotenv before `npm install`

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, dotenv

I have to work with some packages in the private registry. So, in my `package.json` in the dependencies section I have a lines like this one:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "@myco/my-awesome-package": "^0.4.5",
    ...
}
...
```

There is authentication required for the private registry, so I have to create the `.npmrc` file in my project:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
@myco:registry=https://myco-registry-path/
//myco-registry-path/:username=${MYCO_REGISTRY_USER}
//myco-registry-path/:_password=${MYCO_REGISTRY_PASSWORD_BASE64}
```

Yes, I know about `_authToken`, but in my case it is easier to use user and password.

Anyway, here you can see two env variables: `${MYCO_REGISTRY_USER}` and `${MYCO_REGISTRY_PASSWORD_BASE64}` which I have to replace **before** `npm install`.
I know the very simple solution for this problem: put them to the "global" env variables for example to my .bash_profile (or any terminal profile of your choice).
But I do not want to keep variables like this in the "global" scope because the are important only for the current project. What I want to do is to use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). I want to create a `.env` file in the root of my project:

```
MYCO_REGISTRY_USER=myco-registry-username-value
MYCO_REGISTRY_PASSWORD_BASE64=myco-registry-password-value-base64
```

I want that this values replace env variables in my `.npmrc` on the install action. But when I try `npm install` I get an error: `Error: Failed to replace env in config: ${MYCO_REGISTRY_USER}`. I can understand why it happens. Possibly because npm reads `.npmrc` values first and try to replace env variables and fails, because in this moment it know nothing about dotenv.
My question is how to deal with it?

Short summary:

1. I do not want to keep env variables in the terminal profile, instead I want to put it in the `.env` file inside my project.
2. I have to replace env variables in the `.npmrc` file with dotenv **before** `npm install`

Comment: you should run scripting which may copy the configuration variables from .npmrc and create .env.

Answer (score 8):

I know this answer might come too late, but in case anyone else is looking for answers, here's a solution:

You need to prepend your scripts with [dotenv-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-cli) as so:

```
dotenv npm install
```

or in my case where the file was not `.env`:

```
dotenv -e .env.local npm install
```

The problem is that you cannot save this anywhere so that someone can use it with "npm install" somehow. Definitely `npm preinstall` is run *after* reading `.npmrc` so it fails too.

You will need to either document it well or just include a small shell script, but if you're supporting different OSs then it can get funny really fast...

Happily so, CD platforms like Netlify allow you to set environment variables manually.

But I guess this must not be the nicest of starts if someone clones your repo and the first they've got is a failing `npm install` ‍♂️

Also, check this one out: [locking-the-vault-on-font-awesome-npm-tokens](https://blog.fontawesome.com/locking-the-vault-on-font-awesome-npm-tokens-2/)

Comment: There are so many posts/issues/tweets/comments about this across the interwebs but this is by far the best (most contained) solution. Thank you! Gotta get some upvotes!

Comment: And if you don't want to install dotenv-cli globally you can `npx dotenv-cli -e .env.local npm i`.
Too bad npm cannot read .env itself.